# SQLite select most common

Tags: sql, sqlite

The table is look like:

```
A        B
----------
John     a
John     a
Peter    a
Mary     b
Ann      b
Ann      b
```

I want the result is group by B and select the most common word from A:

```
A        B
----------
John     a
Ann      b
```

Comment: What SQLite version do you use?

Comment: Using SQLite version 3.9.1

Answer (score 0):

First I calculate the number of B,A combinations, then per B I calculate the maximum number (MaxN), and finally in the outer query the count is calculated again, but only the lines are shown which have `maxN=COUNT(*)`:

```
SELECT t.B, t.A, COUNT(*) as N
FROM Table t LEFT JOIN 
(SELECT B, MAX(N) AS MaxN
FROM (
  SELECT B, A, count(*) as N
  FROM Table
  GROUP BY B, A) as c 
GROUP BY B) as mx on t.B=mx.B
GROUP BY t.B, t.A
HAVING mx.MaxN=COUNT(*);
```